# There are N jointly distributed Gaussian random variables, complex in nature, and are uncorrelated. How to prove, they are statistically independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

I came across this as a property, but wanted to prove it myself, but can't get through with the proof. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hopefully you found my answer below helpful; if so would you please consider upvoting / accepting. Stackexchange sites survive by people donating their time to help each other, and that is an easy way to give back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this true?

Suppose we let $Z = X + i Y$, with $X,Y \sim N(0,1)$ independent and Normally distributed, and let $W_n$ be i.i.d. draws from a uniform distribution on $\{-1,1\}$, i.e.

$$\mathbf P[ W_n = 1] = \mathbf P[W_n = -1] = \frac12,$$

(often referred to as the Rademacher distribution). Now define

$$Z_n  = W_n Z, \qquad n = 1,\ldots, N.$$

Clearly the $Z_n$ are not independent, since for example

$$ \mathbf P[ Z_n = \pm z \, | \, Z_1 = z ] = 1, \qquad n = 1,\ldots, N.$$

And then computing the covariance we have for any $m \neq n$

\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}(Z_m,Z_n) & = \mathbf E[ Z_m Z_n ] - \mathbf E[Z_m] \mathbf E[Z_n] \\
& = \mathbf E[ Z_m Z_n] \\
& = \mathbf E[ W_m W_n Z^2] \\
& = \mathbf E[W_m] \mathbf E[W_n] \mathbf E[Z^2] \\
& = 0,
\end{align*}
where in the first line we used the fact that $\mathbf E[Z_n] = 0$, and in the last line we used independence of the $W_n$, and the fact that $\mathbf E [W_n] = 0$.

Comment: Although X and Y are random variables in the usual sense - they have distribution functions, Z does not have a distribution function.  Therefore Z is not, strictly speaking, a random variable.

Comment: I think this depends on the interpretation of the poster's reference to *complex Gaussian*. The standard probabilistic definition is to consider a complex Gaussian to be as I described: $Z = X + iY$, ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution)). In this context there is a natural definition of expectation $$\mathbf E[Z] =\mathbf{E}[X] + i\,\mathbf{E}[Y].$$ This is the interpretation that I assumed was intended in the question...

Comment: Alternatively, the poster may have been intended the case of complex Gaussian measures on $\phi \in \mathcal{C}^N$ where $$d \mu(\phi) \propto e^{- \phi A \overline \phi} d \overline \phi_1 d \phi_1 \cdots d \overline \phi_N d \phi_N,$$ with $A$ a matrix with positive Hermitian part. In this sense I agree that the notion of expectation and covariance are less well defined. But so too are the notions of independence, and correlation.

Comment: @ herb steinberg, I'm inferring that you are really getting at the question posed being ill defined, but hopefully the comments above help to clarify why this need not be the case.

Comment: The main point of my comment was - how can a distribution function be defined?

Comment: As before, there are two answers depending on the interpretation. In the first case $Z = X + i\,Y$ then you can define a bivariate distribution function $$f_Z = f_Z(x,y) = \mathbf P[ X \in d x, \, Y \in dy]$$, so there is no difference to the distribution of a standard bivariate Normal distribution. Then you can define expectation of a function $g \colon \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ by $$\mathbf E[ g] = \int_{\mathbb C} g(x,y) d x dy.$$

Comment: Of course the above should have said $$\mathbf E[g] = \int_{\mathbb C} g(x,y) f_Z(x,y) dx dy,$$(ran out of time to correct before comment was locked). In the case that $g = \text{id}$ this simplifies to give the formula for the expectation that I gave above.

Comment: In the second interpretation, defined above in my comment about complex Gaussian measures the density function has been explicitly stated: it is proportional to $e^{-\phi A \overline \phi}$. However in this instance we are talking about a *complex measure*, and the theory starts to differ from standard probability theory. It remains true, however, that this is a class of mathematical objects referred to as complex Gaussian variables (or fields, in the multivariate case).